# What episode of The Fairly OddParents did Cosmo say "three rights make a left"?

Tags: episode-identification, the-fairly-oddparents

The [IMDB quotes page](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0235918/characters/nm0358460) for The Fairly OddParents has the following quote:

> Wanda : Two wrongs don't make a right.
>
> Cosmo : But three rights make a left, and now it's time for the show!

I believe the quote was near the end of an episode and was followed by Cosmo dancing and singing "La Cucaracha" before Wanda blasted him with a hose. What episode of The Fairly OddParents is that quote/scene from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from [The Switch Glitch](https://fairlyoddparents.fandom.com/wiki/The_Switch_Glitch)

> Wanda then tells Timmy that two wrongs don't make a right (meaning
> that everything he put Vicky through made him just as horrible as
> her), but Cosmo jokingly says **"Three rights make a left, and now, it's
> time for the show!"** Wanda, tired of his lackluster rendition of "La
> Cucaracha", turns into a fire hose and blasts him again.